# How to pass variable arguments to my scala program?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am very new to scala spark. Here I have a wordcount program wherein I pass the inputfile as an argument instead of hardcoding it and reading it. But when I run the program I get an error  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException : 0

I think it's because I have not mentioned the argument I am taking in the main class but don't know how to do so.

I tried running the program as is and also tried changing the run configurations. i do not know how to pass the filename (in code) as an argument in my main class

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructType,StructField,StringType};
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;

object First {
 def main(args : Array[String]): Unit = {
   val filename = args(0)
   val cf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Tutorial").setMaster("local")
   val sc = new SparkContext(cf)
   val input = sc.textFile(filename)
   val w = input.flatMap(line => line.split(" ")).map(word=> 
   (word,1)).reduceByKey(_ + _)
   w.collect.foreach(println)
   w.saveAsTextFile(args(1))
  } 


}
```

I wish to run this program by passing the right arguments (input file and save output file as arguments) in my main class. I am using scala eclipse IDE. I do not know what changes to make in my program please help me out here as I am new.

Comment: `<your running command> argument1 argument2`? I think you should use the command line interface.

Comment: Seems standard here.

Answer (score 0):

In the run configuration for the project, there is an option right next to main called '(x)=Arguments' where you can pass in arguments to main in the 'Program Arguments' section.

Additionally, you may print args.length to see the number of arguments your code is actually receiving after doing the above.

Comment: I tried the run configurations but still couldn't obtain the output. Maybe I am doing it wrong while passing the argument. Is it possible that you could send a screenshot of how to pass the arguments in the run config? The input file is something like C:\ofajcdnkz\spark scala\input.txt

Comment: So instead of using the pathname directly in the script you're passing the pathname as an argument?

Comment: Yes. Update: I tried it and I'm able to obtain an output. Now do I pass another empty textfile as second argument in order to save my output in that?

Comment: pass the path of the output file, with the input and output path separated by spaces.

Comment: so I run in program arguments with these two arguments: C:\obr/sparkscala/input_1.txt C:\obr/sparkscala/s.txt                                                                       the first being the existing input file and second an output path however I obtain an error: ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 1.0                       ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 1 times; aborting job

Comment: Try `w.collect().foreach(println)` instead of `w.collect.foreach(println)`

Comment: @ twothreezarsix  No that command works fine. i am talking about the .saveAsTextFile(args(1)) which does not run i.e save output as a textfile

Comment: The code seems to be correct.Do notify if you get it to work

Comment: Update: yes my code is fine. It's an admin privilege issue on my PC sorry or the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are running Spark on Windows, so I'm not sure if this will work exactly as-is, but you can definitely pass arguments like any normal command line application. The only difference is that you have to pass the arguments AFTER specifying the Spark-related parameters.

For example, the JAR filename is `the.jar` and the main object is `com.obrigado.MyMain`, then you could run a Spark submit job like so: `spark-submit --class com.obrigado.MyMain the.jar path/to/inputfile`. I believe `args[0]` should then be `path/to/inputfile`.

However, like any command-line program, it's generally better to use POSIX-style arguments (or at least named arguments), and there are several good ones out there. Personally, I love using [Scallop](https://github.com/scallop/scallop) as it's easy to use and doesn't seem to interfere with Spark's own CLI parsing library.

Hopefully this fixes your issue!

Comment: thank you for answering. Yes I am on windows. I am not having an issue with passing the inpu file as an argument but with my second argument which is to save my output file. When I pass a second path (a txt file) as my second argument I am not able to obtaining the required output

Comment: Sorry for not reading the question thoroughly. `spark-submit --class com.obrigado.MyMain the.jar path/to/inputfile path/to/outputfile` and `args[1]` should have the value `path/to/outputfile`